# iframe makes menu bar buttons go away

Tags: html, iframe

Hey i have a webpage and when i add a iframe on an empty page apart from the navigational menu at the top, the buttons disappear.

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/FWAA6WYz

I am fairly new to HTML, and wouldn't know a lot of the advance stuff. But it would be helpful if i can get like a code to add to it or change up.

I have already tried some of the code i have on the internet that stops stuff like images from moving around but nothing worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your paste bin shows

```
<iframe src="http://www.dota2.com/heroes" width=1080px height= 600px</iframe>
```

Amend it to:

```
<iframe src="http://www.dota2.com/heroes" width=1080px height= 600px></iframe>
```